# R Bar chart with non-correlative and repeated timestamps

Tags: r

I have a table with timestamps(V1) and values(v2):

```
> t
     V1     V2
1     0 132008
2    35      8
3   154 132008
4   154      8
5   847     24
6  2944     62
```

And I would like to plot a chronological bar chart starting from time 0 and ending with the last time in the table. So, for the timestamps with an assigned value, I should put a bar with it. While for the instants without a value, I should keep clear this point in the chart.

Taking into account the example above, I am supposed to have in the X axis the values 0,1,2...2944 with bars when needed (0,35,154,...). Furthermore, some of the instants can be found repeated, in this case this point in the X axis should have 2 bars.

I know that the problem is uncommon, but I hope it will be explained clear enough.
Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly does your _code_ break? Please narrow down your question. People are willing to help if you show some effort towards achieving your goal.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Well, more than break is that I am not sure of how to deal with the problem. Anyway, that's what I have:  
    i <- c(0,35,154,154,847,2944)
j <- c(132008,8,132008,8,24,62)  
t<-cbind(i,j)  
barplot(t, main="Title", ylab= "Total", beside=TRUE)    

And what I want is to put a bar in "0" of heigth "132008", a bar in the instant "35" of heigth "8"...

Comment: @RomanLuštrik more information. If I run barplot(j, main="Title", ylab= "Total", beside=TRUE) I start to get what I want, but the bars do not taken into account the timestamps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- read.table(header=T,text='     V1     V2
1     0 132008
2    35      8
3   154 132008
4   154      8
5   847     24
6  2944     62')
```

This is by using only the standard plot function:

```
plot(x=df$V1,y=df$V2,type='h',lwd=3)
```

[image]

I don't really like the above though.
So you could also try the following library which is better:

```
library(ggplot2) #load library
library(scales)  #load this for axis number formatting
ggplot( df, aes(x=V1,y=V2)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) #plot
```

[image]

Note that you might want to limit your y axis with the ylim argument because due to the high difference between 132008 and 8 the low values won't even show.

Hope it helps

Comment: Great! The first one works, but the second through me "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function."

Comment: Are you using it in a function? I don't really know how you use ggplot in your code to help.

Comment: This is my code: f<-read.table('f.data', sep="\t", header=FALSE)
ggplot(f, aes(x=V1,y=V2)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) and I am getting this error: position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect. Any Idea?

Comment: I'll follow your advice! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't worry for this warning. It says that you probably have lot's of data and some are lost (only visually) because of the width of the bars. You can set the width with the binwidth argument if you want to account for this. check [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_histogram.html)